# jQuery Radio Buttons... basic function can't get to work

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

First attempt at using jQuery, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to get a basic functionality to work. I've got 2 radio buttons on a form, and depending on which one is selected, will update the value of an input text box in the same form. For the life of me I cannot get this to work! the same code will work if I choose to update an "h2" tag, or even the property of the text label next to the input text box. My jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name=RGType]').click(function(){
        var CompType = ($('input:radio[name=RGType]:checked').val());
        //alert(CompType) // this works
        $('#txt_Computername').text(CompType);
    });
});
```

The area of HTML is as follows:

```
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right"><label for="RGType" id="t_Type">Computer Type:</label></td>
    <td>
        <label><input type="radio" name="RGType" value="SECDES" id="RGType_0">Desktop</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="RGType" value="SECLAP" id="RGType_1">Laptop</label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right"><label for="txt_Computerame" id="t_Computername"><span class="required">* </span>Computer Name:</label></td>
    <td><input id="txt_Computername" type="text" name="Computername" alt="Computer Name" style="width:60%" value="test" /></td>
    </tr>
```

Using Firebug, it correctly identifies the current value in the text box as "test" - so I must be locating the correct element. If I change the text to be updated to #t_Computername (the adjecent label) it works!

What AM I missing???

thanks for any advice... sorry for dumb basic question!

Regards...

Comment: Forgot to add, the HTML for the radio buttons directly above the text box is:

Comment: Use `.val()` instead of the `.text()`.

Comment: You won't believe it, but [googleing for `jquery set input value`](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+set+input+value) actually helps! It shows the [documentation for jQuery's `.val` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) as first result.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you want:

```
$('#txt_Computername').val(CompType);
```

You need to use **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** to set value for `input` element not `text()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your

```
$('#txt_Computername').text(CompType);
```

with

```
$('#txt_Computername').val(CompType);
```